Conditional return type based on property value
Why does the following not compile?
function foo<T extends { canBeNull?: boolean }>(x: T): T extends { canBeNull: true }
  ? string | null
  : string
{
  if (x.canBeNull) {
    // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T extends { canBeNull: true; } ? string | null : string'.(2322)
    return null;
  }

  return "...";
}

I've tried a type predicate and exact equality with true; neither makes a difference.
I've seen several similar questions but the explanations were not clear and did not solve my problem.

• "I've seen several similar questions but the explanations were not clear and did not solve my problem." Where are these? • What do you expect the return type of foo({ canBeNull: Math.random() < 0.99 }) to be?

See this question. It's a missing feature, documented at ms/TS#33912 where the workarounds are either just use type assertions, or some convoluted conditionalProducingIf code that looks like this playground link.

@jcalz Yes, the current check is just for truthiness. I noted that I've done === true as well as a type predicate check with the same results.

@jcalz Thanks - I missed that question. That seems clearer than most. Closing mine as a duplicate.

The feature request mentioned by @jcalz is the answer to the question. In the meantime, you can locally exclude the false case: return null as T extends { canBeNull: true } ? string | null : never;

I was trying to demonstrate that Math.random()<0.99 produces a boolean but your function decides that's the same as false (because boolean extends true is false). You need to make your return type distribute over unions in T["canBeNull"].

@jcalz I see - the property value could be nondeterministic. Good point.
